# Trying to insert data into sql database using python

Tags: python, sql, database, xampp

I am trying to insert my details into sql database using python and xampp but whenever i try to do so it always prompts me the error "Error due to: (1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Here is my `create.py` code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import register
import menu

import pymysql

class Create:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Create New Timetable")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        framecreate = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        framecreate.place(x=450, y=100, height=500, width=700)
        venuecreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the venue", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=50,y=100)
        self.venue=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.venue.place(x=50, y=130, width=250)
        capacitycreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the capacity of the venue", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=370,y=100)
        self.venuepax=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.venuepax.place(x=370, y=130, width=250)
        timecreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the time", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=50,y=170)
        self.time=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.time.place(x=50, y=200, width=250)
        lecturercreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the lecturer", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=370,y=170)
        self.lecturer=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.lecturer.place(x=370, y=200, width=250)
        modulercreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the module", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=50,y=240)
        self.subject=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.subject.place(x=50, y=270, width=250)
        departmentcreate = Label(framecreate, text="Please add the department", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), fg="orange").place(x=370,y=240)
        self.department=Entry(framecreate,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.department.place(x=370, y=270, width=250)
        addbutton = Button(framecreate, text="Add", command=self.adddetails, bg="white", fg="orange",
                              font=("trebuchet ms", 12)).place(x=50, y=350)
        nextbutton = Button(framecreate, text="Next", command="", bg="white", fg="orange",
                           font=("trebuchet ms", 12)).place(x=50, y=400)


def adddetails(self):
    if self.venue.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Field cannot be left empty!!",parent=self.root)
    else:
        try:
            con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="timetable")
            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into timetable list (venue,venuepax,time,lecturer,module,department) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                            (self.venue.get(),self.venuepax.get(),self.time.get(),self.lecturer.get(),self.subject.get(),self.department.get()))
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            messagebox.showinfo("Success","Registration Successful",parent=self.root)
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)

def CreateForm():
    win = Tk()
    obj = Create(win)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Create(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As I am trying to add the details in my database, the error states that "Error due to: (1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

The values of my table are as such

```
1 id Primary    int(10)         
2   venue   varchar(50) 
3   venuepax    int(10) 
4   time    varchar(50) 
5   lecturer    varchar(50) 
6   module  varchar(50) 
7   department  varchar(50)
```

Comment: if i were to venture a guess, i'd say your data types aren't matching the columns. What's the schema for the table? I'd be most suspecious of the `time` field

Comment: @Macattack i have updated my table details

Comment: you should make sure `venuepax` is an `int` when sent to `execute`. If it's treated as a string it'll get quoted and then the database won't like it. Also remove `list` like Chuma said

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
cur.execute("insert into timetable list (venue,venuepax,time,lecturer,module,department) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                            (self.venue.get(),self.venuepax.get(),self.time.get(),self.lecturer.get(),self.subject.get(),self.department.get()))
```

to

```
cur.execute("""insert into timetable (venue,venuepax,time,lecturer,module,department) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                            (self.venue.get(),self.venuepax.get(),self.time.get(),self.lecturer.get(),self.subject.get(),self.department.get()))
```

The "list" after the table timetable should be removed.
You should also follow python string syntax - 3 double quotes/parenthesis instead of 1 around statements.

Comment: If the answers don’t work because we don’t have any idea into the source data, set your values to local variables before you use them in the query so you know what they are. Also I don’t know what a data type of  INT(10) is. Closest thing I’ve encountered to that is when defining a precision number either as a decimal in MSSQL or a NUMERIC in ORACLE.